# Different REST url for one model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an ember application with a few different models. All bar one model pull data from an api at http://example.com/version1/123/. However, one model needs to pull from http://example.com/version1/dogs/123. Is it possible to add a custom url for one model? I've tried changing my store.js file as follows-

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://example.com/version1/123/'
});

App.Store.registerAdapter('App.Dogs', DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://example.com/version1/dogs/123'
}));
```

but it hasn't had an effect. Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of Ember Data are you using? Is your model named "Businesses" or "Business"?

Comment: Sorry got confused while trying to make code generic- it's plural, see edit

Comment: Ember- Data 1.0.0-beta.5+canary.d6015888

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the register adapter and just create a custom adapter for dogs (This might need to be singular)

```
App.DogsAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://example.com/version1/dogs/123/'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, something like this should work

```
App.DogAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://example.com/version1/dogs/123'
});
```

I have it setup personally with namespace over host like this.

```
App.DogAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: "version1/dogs"
});
```